# Dynamically add a new maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I need to add a new maven dependency to my maven project when project is built by the continuous integration server, but the dependency should not be there when developers are building the project locally.

Is there a way to dynamically add the dependency through a maven plugin so that continuous integration plan can run a maven command and add the dependency by itself?

Comment: That does not make sense. What is the reason for such thing? This would mean the devs are building something different / testing than building on the build server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using profiles is the best way for this kind of case

Here is the example to customize the dependencies inclusion

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>profile-dev</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           depednency A
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>profile-prod</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            dependency B
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  <profiles>
```

To run the build at **dev** box mvn install -P profile-dev

To run the build at **production**  mvn install -P profile-prod